# Angular attach DOM to Component

Tags: angularjs, angular

So in angularjs you had the possibility to define a directive and bind the html template  to an already existing controller. In principal this meant you could reuse the controller for multiple directives, therefore for multiple templates.

```
angular
.module('App')
.component('Name', {
    templateUrl: 'some.html',
    controller: 'someController'
});
```

How can this be performed in Angular. As far as I understood it in Angular Components are directives and always directly bind the html. Basically I want to use another view which only changes the html but keeps the same functionality.

Edit:

Basically I want this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-exercise-list',
    templateUrl: '(MULTIPLE HTML TEMPLATE PATHS HERE)',
    providers: [                      
                ]
})
    export class className{

    //USING THE SAME COMPONENT CODE FOR THE MULTIPLE TEMPLATES

    constructor(){}
}
```

The only option I found so far would be through extending but I think thats overkill.

Comment: You mean change in html as just layout look and feel rest everything same. Isnt it?

Comment: Yes, basically some things in the new template are taken out, therefore some functionality is not used, but the functionality stays the same and it would be rewritten code if I'd create a new component.

Comment: In Angular, a component is a single entity. You can extend it and provide other template for child class.

Comment: You may find some help here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46235412/5468463

Answer (score 0):

### Define `templateUrl` as a function

You can specify `templateUrl` as a string representing the URL **or as a function** which takes two arguments `tElement` and `tAttrs`.

The function takes the following arguments:

- `tElement` - template element - The element where the directive has been declared.
- `tAttrs` - template attributes - Normalized list of attributes declared on this element.

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - templateURL](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-)

Comment: that works for angularJs, i will try something similar and see if it works. But I think extending of the base component is what I have to do

Answer (score 0):

After more research it still seems that the best solution I could come up with is using inheritance.

https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-component-inheritance-and-template-swapping

He has a rather nice description of it

Thank you to all who helped me ;)

Answer (score -1):

There must be some directive in angularjs as ng-if or something like that.

In Angular 4 you can do this as one of way as

```
<div *ngIf="x === 1"></div>
<div *ngIf="x === 2"></div>
```

And you can pass the value of x according to your need.

Added Solution

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Blogger } from '../models/blogger';
import { BloggerProfileService } from '../service/blogger-profile.service';
import { SharedService } from '../service/shared.service';
import { AuthService } from '../auth-service.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'article-author-panel',
  templateUrl: './article-author-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-author-panel.component.css']
})
export class ArticleAuthorPanelComponent {

  @Input('templateType') templateType;
  author;
  blogger : Blogger;
  articleDt;
  user;

  @Input()
    get articleDate(){
      return this.articleDt;
    }

    set articleDate(date){
      this.articleDt = this.sharedService.getUTCDate(new Date(date));
    }
  @Input()

  set articleAuthor(author) {
    this.author = author;
    this.bloggerProfileService.getBlogger(author)
    .take(1)
    .subscribe((blogger) => {
      this.blogger = blogger;
    })
  }

  get articleAuthor() {
    return this.author;
  }

  constructor(
    private bloggerProfileService: BloggerProfileService,
    private sharedService: SharedService,
    private router : Router,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
    authService.user$
    .take(1)
    .subscribe((user) => {
      if(user) this.user = user;
    });
  }

  clickFollow(){
    if(this.user === null || this.user === undefined){
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }

}
```

Template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="templateType === 1">
    <div class="row no-gutters" style="border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0; padding-top:5px;">
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/170000/velka/spinach-leaves-1461774375kTU.jpg" alt="Person" class="aap-image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-9">
                    <div class="aap-b-detail" *ngIf="blogger">
                        <span class="aap-b-name">{{ blogger.name }}</span>
                        <br />
                        <span class="aap-b-summary">{{ blogger.summary }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <button class="aap-follow" (click)="clickFollow()">Follow</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="templateType === 2">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/170000/velka/spinach-leaves-1461774375kTU.jpg" alt="Person" class="aap-image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-9">
                    <div class="aap-b-detail aap-b-detail-lh" *ngIf="blogger">
                        <span class="aap-b-name">{{ blogger.name }}</span>
                        <br />
                        <span class="aap-b-summary">{{ blogger.summary }}</span>
                        <br />
                        <span class="aap-b-date">{{ articleDate }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <button class="aap-follow" (click)="clickFollow()">Follow</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

This is my component which I have created where according to the position I placed the component the layout changes. You can consider it as two different htmls connected together as normal if else keeping the behind code same. According to my demand I did not use each variable. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to change the whole template of a component without rewriting the component code. I don't see how ng-if helps me with that sry can you explain that a bit more pls?

Comment: Can you add some sample code of template which explains your requirement?

Comment: basically i Am transofrming an angularjs app to angular: In angular js I used mutpile custom directives with the same controller to perform what I wanted (See example directive above). Therefore mutiple different html templates had the same controller and could be used with the custom directive. Therefore the same controller was used for multiple html templates. I need that in Angular not AngularJS

Comment: If I get you right are you asking how to reuse the component in angular>

Comment: @reviloera in theory yes. same component different view template

Comment: To reuse a component you have to create a module that can be injected in other modules that needs to use the component

Comment: and why isnt my solution appropriate?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala interesting idea that could work, but is unsuitable in my opinion since it would mean that I have 1000 lines + in my html File.

Comment: @Shubham Agarwal Bhewanewala   check my answer if it makes sense

Answer (score -1):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LoadingComponent } from './loading.component'

@NgModule({
imports: [
CommonModule
],
declarations: [LoadingComponent],
exports: [LoadingComponent]
})
export class LoadingModule { }
```

IN this case am planning to reuse the loading component in multiple places. I will be injecting this module on specif area am intending to use loading component

Comment: how will you change the template?

Comment: Mhm... but a module doesn't allow me to change the html template for the given component or does it ?

Comment: What you have done is you made component available outside module when you import LoadingModule

Comment: when you have to conditionally change the template either change template url or do as I mentioned.