# routing to page instead of component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Ok. So I know how to route from one component to another but could I route to a page that in the same component or in any other directory?

Say we are in the component `home`

`home`

- home.component.html
- home.component.css
- home.component.ts
- classes.html

and I want to redirect the user to the page `classes.html` when the user clicks on a button that is in `home.component.html`

and the link should go from `/home` to `/home/classes`

Comment: I think its not possible.But try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235412/angular-2-multiple-html-pages-within-same-component may be its helpful for u

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Angular is made up of components, you need to have a component with particular route configured if you want to navigate within the application.

if not you can use window.href and navigate to the particular page you need to which is not the angular way

Comment: the problem with this is that I will have tuns of components which I don't want to do.

Comment: that is not a proper way to structure your application, you should consider using child components