# I want to include multiple html under same ts file?

Tags: html, angular

I have a single component in which **I want to include multiple HTML files**, 
I am using **Angular 4**, and I want to load all HTML files at the same time.

I checked and found that using **directive** and I can do that, But I am not able to see an example for this.

Can somebody recommend what to use and how to do this?

I have tried this it is not working properly:

```
    import {
  Compiler, Component, Injector, VERSION, ViewChild, NgModule, NgModuleRef,
  ViewContainerRef, AfterViewInit, OnInit
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'mainComponent',
  template: `
    <ng-container #dynamicTemplate></ng-container>
  `
  // or with a templateUrl
})
export class MainComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('dynamicTemplate', {read: ViewContainerRef}) dynamicTemplate;

  constructor(private _compiler: Compiler,
              private _injector: Injector,
              private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let myTemplateUrl = '../first.component.html';


      //myTemplateUrl = './another-template.component.html';


    const tmpCmp = Component({
      moduleId: module.id, templateUrl: myTemplateUrl
    })(class {
    });
    const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {
    });

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
      .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
        const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
        cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
        this.dynamicTemplate.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Pls share atleast minimal codes or working demo in **stackblitz** so that others can understand what have tried so far and what needs to be changed .Have you check this? `<p [innerHTML]='bindWhatYouWantShow'></p>`

Comment: @worstCoder I have added my code

Answer (score 0):

you could try like below.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'register-page',
    template: `
            <div class="open-card-BG" *ngIf="registerView == 'regView1'">Reg View 1 Content</div>
            <div class="open-card-BG" *ngIf="registerView == 'regView2'">Reg View 2 Content</div>
            `,
    styleUrls: ['./register-page.component.scss'],
    providers: [RegisterService, Configuration, LocalStorageService]
})

export class Appcomponent {
    registerView = 'regView1';
}
```

refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235412/angular-2-multiple-html-pages-within-same-component) might help you

Comment: <div class="open-card-BG" *ngIf="registerView == 'regView1'">Reg View 1 Content</div> in this I have to write whole html code, this will be quite big

Comment: <app-page1-component></app-page1-component> this is selector what is used in the thred,  so can we create selector for html pages  ?

Comment: @DebashishDwivedi yes the 2nd approach might help if you have too much contents to load. actually its better to separate