# Is there a way to have 2 html templates with on angular component?

Tags: angular

I need to refactor some code, since my HTML template is getting pretty long. Is there any way you know of, I can reference to 2 templates with one component?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make another component?

Comment: i think the best way to do it is to split your big html to be small component

Answer (score 0):

No. It kind of beats the point of working in components. The best approach would be to extract anything re-usable or at least partially independent and make a component out of it.

For example, if it's a wizard like component you'd like to create, create step components.

Look at the example here: [older stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235412/angular-2-multiple-html-pages-within-same-component)

In traditional angularjs, there was the ng-include component which did what you are asking for but it's not going to be included in angular 2+. [Github discussion about it](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7596)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple templates on single components, and angular isn't supposed to work that way. The thing you can do to achieve the same, is by [conditional rendering](https://reactgo.com/angular-conditional-attribute-directive/). Or else you can use the [ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355236/render-content-between-the-component-tags) directive to dynamically insert html to the child component, which will be actually inserted from the parent between the child components.