# Angular load dynamic HTML component

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-template, angular-dynamic-components

I have to create two different themes for an angular application. Each theme needs to be loaded based on a property from an API call. I would like to create two HTML files that will use the same .ts code, because the functionality will remain the same.

Whats is the best approach to have this implemented. Right now this implementation is made using ngSwitch inside .html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQVsB.png)

Comment: does this solve ur question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235412/angular-2-multiple-html-pages-within-same-component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create two different presentational components. Pass data to those components from the parent component. Switch between components from using ngIf.

```
<presentation-component-one *ngIf="isThemeOne" [data]="data"></presentation-component-one>
<presentation-component-two *ngIf="isThemeTwo" [data]="data"></presentation-component-two>
```